# Laravel/React: barryvdh/laravel-cors handling preflight HTTP OPTIONS request

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, cors

Just getting started with `barryvdh/laravel-cors`. I have a server side application running on port 8000 which authenticates users via Laravel Passport, and my react.js client application running on port 3000. Right now I'm trying to get a "login" action working.

From the client when I provide correct credentials a token is sent back and the status is 200. When the credentials are invalid a 401 is returned. So good so far. However, if I provide only an email in the form and no password I get the following CORS related error:

[image: errors]

When the error is thrown, the following network calls occur:

[image]

My login on the client side:

```
login = (email, password) => {
    console.log(email);
    fetch("http://localhost:8000/api/auth/login", {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({
            'email': email,
            'password': password
        }),
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response['access_token']); //with correct credentials this is logged out and set in local storage
        localStorage.setItem('access_token', response['access_token']);
    })
    .catch(error => console.error('Error: ', error));
}
```

Server side:

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'email' => 'required|string|email',
        'password' => 'required|string',
        'remember_me' => 'boolean'
    ]);

    $credentials = request(['email', 'password']);

    if(!Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Unauthorized'
        ], 401);
    }

    $user = $request->user();
    $tokenResult = $user->createToken('Personal Access Token');
    $token = $tokenResult->token;

    if ($request->remember_me) {
        $token->expires_at = Carbon::now()->addWeeks(1);
    }

    $token->save();
    return response()->json([
        'access_token' => $tokenResult->accessToken,
        'token_type' => 'Bearer',
        'expires_at' => Carbon::parse(
            $tokenResult->token->expires_at
        )->toDateTimeString()
    ]);
}
```

`cors.php` (published from barryvdh/laravel-cors package):

```
return [
    'supportsCredentials' => false,
    'allowedOrigins' => ['*'],
    'allowedOriginsPatterns' => [],
    'allowedHeaders' => ['*'],
    'allowedMethods' => ['*'],
    'exposedHeaders' => [],
    'maxAge' => 0,
];
```

`api.php`:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'auth',], function () {
    Route::post('login', 'AuthController@login');
    Route::post('register', 'AuthController@register');
    Route::get('register/activate/{token}', 'AuthController@registerActivate');
    Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function() {
        Route::get('logout', 'AuthController@logout');
        Route::get('user', 'AuthController@user');
    });
});
```

`Kernel.php`:

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        \Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors::class,
        'throttle:60,1',
        'bindings',
    ],
];

protected $middleware = [
    \Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class
];
```

Making the same POST request (one to `/api/auth/login` with the password excluded) via postman I get the expected error message:

```
{
    "message": "The given data was invalid.",
    "errors": {
        "password": [
            "The password field is required."
        ]
    }
}
```

But, making this through the react client application the error in the screenshot is thrown. I'm guessing this has something to do with the preflight HTTP OPTIONS request that the browser sends out as part of how CORS works.

How can I correct this? I'd expect a 401 to be returned for the status and for the react client to get the same JSON message that Postman receives in the case that the password is empty. It just seems weird that based on the payload for that POST request, a CORS related error occurs. Does this mean that the server and/or client is not setting up CORS correctly?

Comment: Both the laravel and react app need to send CORS headers correctly. If you can avoid CORS redirects it makes things a lot easier to deal with

Comment: I thought only the server side needed to set CORS related headers. What headers does the client side need to set? I don't think I can avoid CORS redirects

Comment: The react app seems to be served from a different server there's localhost:3000 and localhost:8000 both being accessed by the client so both of those need CORS headers

Comment: can you add your CORS configuration for backend in the question ?

Comment: Added. I should have posted that earlier - I'm not totally convinced that I've set that part up right. I think what I have is just the default config settings from the `barryvdh/laravel-cors` package

Comment: have you ran the command `php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Barryvdh\Cors\ServiceProvider"` ?

Comment: yes. that's where `cors.php` came from

Comment: seems great at this point, can you please add `config/app.php` content and the middlewares section in your `Kernel.php` also ?

Comment: Nothing has changed in `app.php` relating to the cors package should there be a change there? will post kernel.php

Comment: may I ask why there's a need for different ports?

Comment: I'm using different ports for development since when I actually deploy this application as a whole, the Laravel API will be served by an Nginx web server and the React application will be served via node. Basically, I'm trying to keep a complete division between the client and the server side - hope that sort of makes sense

Comment: @Ronald just to clarify: different ports are used because locally I have 2 servers running. One serving the php application and one serving the react application

Comment: i see that `\Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors::class,` is declared in both `$middleware` and `$middlewareGroups`, can you try removing it from the `$middlewareGroups` section, one other thing, i've noticed that many people are having that issue and it seems related to the version of the package, what version are you using ? Have a look at this issues : [link1](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors/issues/239), [link2](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors/issues/278)

Comment: I tried to remove the entry in `$middlewareGroups` - doesn't seem to make a difference. I'm using the latest release (0.11.3). I think I found the problem - on the server side I'm requiring the password (in the call to `$request->validate(...)`) when this validation fails (due to client not providing a password) it seems like the CORS middleware doesn't completely run - it fails right there. Changing this field to being optional on the server side (which of course is not a good idea) results in a 401 being returned when no password is provided (therefore invalid user/pass combo)

Comment: @AbdelkarimELAMEL you should put your comments as an answer - specifically the 2nd link that you provided and the github info there about "When an error occurs, the middleware isn't run completely". That was the problem. I just didn't see that in the repo and wasn't expecting a CORS related error. Thanks for your help

Comment: you're welcome, i'll add that as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the error is thrown when an error occurs in your backend.

As mentioned in the [docs](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors#common-problems-and-errors-pre-laravel-53) :

> When an error occurs, the middleware isn't run completely. So when
>   this happens, you won't see the actual result, but will get a CORS
>   error instead.

This [issue](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors/issues/278) helped figuring the source of the error

Answer (score 1):

**First of all the class member:**

```php
protected $middleware
```

Will apply the middleware for both `api` and `web`

**From** [laravel.com/docs/5.8/middleware#registering-middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/middleware#registering-middleware)

> If you want a middleware to run during every HTTP request to your application, list the middleware class in the $middleware property of your app/Http/Kernel.php class.

**See also:** [barryvdh/laravel-cors#global-usage](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors#global-usage)

So try to register your middleware one time by removing:
`\Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors::class` of your `'api'` **middleware group**.

And for logical purposes refactor your `protected $middleware` with:

```php
protected $middleware = [
    \App\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
    \Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors::class,
];
```